# Laravel routes issue when loaded using a vhost alias

Tags: apache, laravel, laravel-5

I have an existing website: test.local and it already contains a script (wordpress). I want to make the /test and /test2 respond with laravel 5.4 so I modified the vhost file to also include 2 aliases (for /test and /test2):

```
Alias /test "/var/www/path/site/public"
Alias /test2 "/var/www/path/site/public"
<Directory /var/www/path/site/public>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

If I access /test and /test2 it works.

The issue is that in routes/web.php I want to have:

```
Route::any('/test/ok', [
  'as'   => 'index',
  'uses' => 'Frontend\Index@index'
]);
```

but when accessing on the browser it seems I can't access it with: http://test.local/test/ok BUT with http://test.local/test/test/ok . I could remove from the route '/test' and leave only '/ok' but then when I generate the route (by name) it will be http://test.local/ok which won't be trapped by the vhost alias.

Any solutions to this? (besides redefining routes function helper to also include "\test" on all the calls.

Thank you!

Comment: Solved it with a symlink and modifying the original .htaccess.